# Angular - Redirect if page not specified in routes

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I'm using routes so I've specified my various pages like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/'...

.when('/login'...

.when('/story'...
```

However if a user types something not in that list it shows (as expected) a blank ng-view. I'd rather they are redirected to the home page.

How do i do that - "if a page (`when`) is not specified in routes direct to homepage"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'otherwise' option in the router:

```
 .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})
```

Comment: Ah! Can't belive i didn't spot that on the docs page! Thanks.

Comment: Also - using otherwise would this essentially cover me from the user ever seeing a 404?

Comment: Believe so, or can make a custom 404 template and throw that up

Answer (score 1):

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider